# How to identify if an email is a duplicate within a date range in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a data set of email sends that includes a contact's email and the day they were sent. I want to identify the "sends" that were sent less than three months after being sent to the same email. It looks something like this:

```
Contact email   Date Sent  
jim@live.com    1/19/18
gary@live.com   1/20/18
pedro@live.com  2/4/18
mark@live.com   3/4/18
gary@live.com   3/4/18
```

In this case, I want to create a dummy variable that gives a value of 1 if the send was within three months of a previous send. Using the example above, only gary@live.com on 3/4/18 would have a 1, and all else would have a 0, because the second send was within 3 months of Gary's first send on 1/20/18.

What code in excel could I use to create this dummy variable?

I've tried using this code: =IFERROR(IF(B4=B3,IF(DATEDIF(K3,K4,"m")<=3,1,0),0),0) but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

If sorting is an option, sort by Name (column A), then by Date (column B) and then use the following formula in column C:

```
=IF(AND(A3=A2,B3-B2<90),1,"")
```

Comment: So using your example, gary will be in rows 2 and 3 and cell C3 (which contains `=IF(AND(A3=A2,B3-B2<90),1,"")`) will evaluate to "1"

Comment: Cell C4 contains `=IF(AND(A4=A3,B4-B3<90),1,"")` and so on down the line.

Comment: Cell C4 evaluates to nothing because row 4 contains jim and row 3 contains gary.